# Android App Bundle - native code library failed to load

Tags: android-app-bundle

I need to replace the APK to App Bundle feature.
My app using some SDK with native libraries.

1. The app build.gradle dependencies countains:
        implementation files ('libs / refsi.jar')
        implementation files ('libs / tsi.jar')
2. The SDK native libraries (two .so files for each architecture) placed under   /app/src/main/jniLibs/  (armeabi-v7a  |  arm64-v8a |  x86  |  x86_64 |  armeabi)

I tried to use googles instructions, and I was looking for help, but after I download the app from google play to my test device, the SDK was not working  -  the log file shows that the files not found.
"...Native code library failed to load. dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[
[zip file "/data/app/ ....

Please help me understand the correct and simple way to use an app bundle in that case.

Comment: are you loading them from dynamic features and, if so, are you using https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/playcore#load_native_libs?

Comment: Having the same issue.

Comment: same issue, did you find a way out ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Posted similar question on SO but no answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62807988/android-app-bundle-only-native-library-failed-to-load

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, according to [google doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#behavior-changes)

> When building an Android App Bundle, APKs generated from that app bundle that target Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher now include uncompressed versions of your native libraries by default. This optimization avoids the need for the device to make a copy of the library and thus reduces the on-disk size of your app. If you'd rather disable this optimization, add the following to your gradle.properties file:

```
android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs = false
```