# Unable to find native libraries after switching to Android App Bundles

Tags: android, java-native-interface

After switching to Android App Bundle, my installed app was unable to find native libraries even though `.aab` file contains them. I found that I have encountered the same issue as described in this question: [Android App Bundle (only) - native library failed to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62807988)

And, the answer to that question suggests to use following Gradle property. This solves my issue.

> android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs = false

But, Gradle 7.0+ introduces this change in the name of optimization.
What are the implications of avoiding this? How can I support it?

---

Here's how I add and find `.so` libraries in my app. I cannot use `System.loadLibrary(...)` at the moment.

I have added `libcore.so` file to `:core` module like this:

```
core / libs / arm64-v8a    / libcore.so
core / libs / armeabi-v7a  / libcore.so
core / libs / x86          / libcore.so
core / libs / x86_64       / libcore.so
```

And, in `AndroidManifest.xml`, I have added following line:

```
android:extractNativeLibs="true"
```

And, in `build.gradle` of `:core` module, I have added `sourceSets` like this:

```
android {
    sourceSets.main {
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }
}
```

I ensure the native library is available like this:

```
private fun ensureNativeLibAvailable(context: Context, fileName: String) {
    val nativeDir = File(context.applicationInfo.nativeLibraryDir)
    findFile(fileName, nativeDir) 
        ?: throw RuntimeException("$fileName not found.") 
}
```

Here, `findFile(...)` function searches for `libcore.so` file in `~~~/lib/arm64/` folder for `arm64-v8a` devices.

After building `.apk` format, I am able to find `libcore.so` using above code. `/data/data/package-name` path has a folder with `lib-main` name. It contains following files:

```
dso_deps
dso_lock
dso_manifest
dso_state
```

---

If I build `.aab` file instead, without using the fix from linked answer, this code fails. `/data/data/package-name` contains four new folders. `lib-0` contains `libcore.so`. `lib-1`, `lib-2`, `lib-main` are, also, present. `dso` files are present in all `lib-*` folders.

Comment: _"What are the implications of avoiding this?"_ That you'll use up more storage space, since there will be two copies of each native library on the device: the compressed one inside the apk/bundle, and its uncompressed counterpart.

Comment: If I continue using the existing code to find native libraries, am I using compressed ones or uncompressed ones?

Comment: Check the file sizes? That should give you the answer.