# Android App bundle install not placing native libs in the lib/$ABI folder

Tags: android, android-app-bundle, android-native-library

In order to try and understand how Android App Bundles deploy native .so I created a simple test app using android studio.

1. The test setup:

I added some test .so's.

[image]

Also added the necessary line to the app's build.gradle file

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
    }
}
```

2. Checked building and installing a `apk` works as expected.

I see the following files/folders in the root of the apk install

```
base.apk
lib
oat
```

the `lib` folder contains `arm64` which contains

```
libexepython2.7.so
libffi.so
```

Note: I expected that bdiff.so would **NOT** be present as it doesn't following the required naming pattern of `lib<name>.so`

So this works as expected.

3. Built Android App Bundle (AAB).

Examining the `AAB`

```
base
BUNDLE-METADATA
META_INF
BundleConfig.pb
```

The `AAB/base` folder contains

```
lib
native.pb
(and others...)
```

I see references to `lib/arm64-v8a` and `lib/armeabi-v7a` in the `native.pb` file.

The `AAB/base/lib/` folder contains

```
arm64-v8a
armeabi-v7a
```

arm64-v8a contains

```
bdiff.so
libexepython2.7.so
libffi.so
```

So all seems reasonably sensible.

4. Converted to `.apks` using bundletool

   `java -jar bundletool.jar build-apks --bundle=release\app-release.aab --output=app.apks --overwrite`

The apks archive contains a `splits` folder with `base-arm64_v8a*.apk` `base-armeabi_v7a*.apk` files.

Confirmed that base-arm64_v8a.zip contains a `lib/arm64-v8a` folder with

```
bdiff.so
libexepython2.7.so
libffi.so
```

5. Installed via bundletool

   `java -jar bundletool.jar install-apks --apks=app.apks`

Looking at the install I see the following files/folders in the root of the apk install.

```
base.apk
lib
oat
split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
split_config.en.apk
split_config.xhdpi.apk
```

the `lib` folder contains `arm64` **which is empty**!

**Question**: Why is the `lib/arm64/` folder empty? Why isn't the app bundle installing .so's?

To rule out bundletool problems, I've also tested installing AAB with google 'internal app sharing' (with a different non test app), and observed similar results.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause**

From the [gradle 3.3.0 release notes](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/past-releases/agp-3-3-0-release-notes)

> When building an Android App Bundle, APKs generated from that app
> bundle that target Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher now include
> uncompressed versions of your native libraries by default. This
> optimization avoids the need for the device to make a copy of the
> library and thus reduces the on-disk size of your app. If you'd rather
> disable this optimization, add the following to your gradle.properties
> file:
>
> android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs = false

So in summary the cause was that for Android App Bundle (AAB) native libraries are not 'installed' by default, but rather uncompressed versions are included in the apk, which I guess the app is expected to somehow use.

**Use compressed and installed native libs when using older Gradles**

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64465044/361714) answer suggested setting `android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false` in the gradle.properties.

**Use compressed and installed native libs when using newer Gradles**

Add the following to the android section of your apps build.gradle file

```
packagingOptions {
    jniLibs {
        useLegacyPackaging = false
    }
}
```

**Use compressed and installed native libs when using Maui**

To do the same when building Android apps with `MAUI`:

1. Create a `BundleConfig.json` file:

   {
   "optimizations" : {
   "uncompress_native_libraries" : {}
   }
   }
2. Add `<AndroidBundleConfigurationFile>BundleConfig.json</AndroidBundleConfigurationFile>` to your MAUI `.csproj` file.

**Verifying the AAB is using compressed native libs**

To tell if you AAB uses uncompressed native libraries, and therefore doesn't extract them on install, run the following command:

```
java -jar bundletool-all.jar dump config --bundle=myapp.aab
```

If the output contains

```
"uncompressNativeLibraries": {
"enabled": true
},
```

OR the output doesn't have `uncompressNativeLibraries` set, then the AAB uses uncompressed native libraries.

If you see

```
"uncompressNativeLibraries": {
},
```

then it uses compressed native libraries and will uncompress them and copy them on app install.

Comment: The uncompressed .so files in the APK are also aligned to 4kb boundaries (in the ZIP structure), so they can be memory mapped into the app process memory (which is AFIK more or less what the regular lib loader does) and then you just have to perform linking the exported/imported symbols.

Comment: Thanks. In my case my app launches a native subprocess and these .so's are required for it.